# Reverse Tethering not working in Android phone vis usb

Tags: reverse-tether

I went through this tutorial http://blog.mathieu.carbou.me/post/60454997009/reverse-usb-tethering-with-android-2-2 to reverse tether my android phone to use PC internet via USB.

Using following commands I am successfully able to create bridge `br0`.

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0
sudo ifconfig usb0 0.0.0.0
sudo brctl addbr br0 
sudo brctl addif br0 eth0
sudo brctl addif br0 usb0
sudo ifconfig br0 up
sudo dhclient br0
```

`br0` has ip address : *172.16.138.102*

My android phone is showing `rndis0`. I used following command using adb shell as root.

```
netcfg rndis0 dhcp
```

`rndis0` was assigned ip : *172.16.138.109/24*

Then I added default gateway for `rndis0` interface.

```
route add default gw 172.16.138.102 dev rndis0
```

Still internet was not working on android. I tried several other tutorials but same info was mentioned everywhere. Am I missing something or I need to do something more for running internet?